# Is there a way to have multiple error messages displayed with RAISERROR conditionally?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, error-handling

I am thinking of something like the CASE statement for RAISERROR, but I want the remaining code to be checked too, and not skip anything after encountering the first RAISERROR. Right now I have something like this.

[image]

Now, I want a way where I can RAISERROR at the very end and do it conditionally. So if there are two errors from three checks, both should be displayed to the user. Thank you.

Comment: Is this happening within a `TRY` / `CATCH`?

Comment: No there is no try/catch block. Maybe I am doing this under the wrong assumption that the code will stop executing anything after the first RAISERROR encounter, if that is at all wrong.

Comment: Okay, so it seems from the answer by Martin Smith that I am entirely wrong. Good to know that user generated errors don't abort the whole batch.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you have posted already does what you want as written.

> [Errors you raise yourself with RAISERROR do not abort the batch, not
>   even in trigger context](http://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/SQL2000-I.html#triggercontext).

You will see that in the screenshot below SSMS manages to display all errors fine. Are you missing some context in your question?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One method is to build an error message string and issue a single `RAISERROR` conditionally after all validations are done.

```
DECLARE @ErrorMessage varchar(2047);
IF @ForeCastYearCheck = 'false'
    SET @ErrorMessage = @ForeCastYearCheckError;
IF @ForeCastQuarterCheck = 'false'
    SET @ErrorMessage = COALESCE(@ErrorMessage + ',' + @ForeCastQuarterCheckError, @ForeCastQuarterCheckError);
IF @ForeCastComboCheck = 'false'
    SET @ErrorMessage = COALESCE(@ErrorMessage + ',' + @ForeCastComboCheckError, @ForeCastComboCheckError);
IF @ErrorMessage IS NOT NULL
    RAISERROR(@ErrorMessage, 16, 1);
```